# How to fill parent for buttons in a GridLayout with columnCount = "3"

Tags: java, android, xml

I have just created a custom num keyboard by XML all I need I want this button which in the grid layout fill the grid layout I tried to put something like weight but it didn't work this is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pKeyBoardId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:editable="false">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <Button
            android:text="1"
            android:id="@+id/n1"/>

        <Button
            android:text="2"
            android:id="@+id/n2"/>
        <Button
            android:text="3"
            android:id="@+id/n3"/>
        <Button
            android:text="4"
            android:id="@+id/n4"/>
        <Button
            android:text="5"
            android:id="@+id/n5"/>
        <Button
            android:text="6"
            android:id="@+id/n6"/>
        <Button
            android:text="7"
            android:id="@+id/n7"/>
        <Button
            android:text="8"
            android:id="@+id/n8"/>
        <Button
        android:text="9"
        android:id="@+id/n9"/>

        <Button
            android:text="CLR"
            android:id="@+id/clear"/>

        <Button
            android:text="0"
            android:id="@+id/n0"/>

        <Button
            android:text="DEL"
            android:id="@+id/del"/>

    </GridLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

all I need these button to fill the GridLayout and I wand to add some spacing If I want to change the back ground color of buttons

I need something like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cM64Y.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this -

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/pKeyBoardId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="none"
    android:editable="false">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <Button
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/n1"/>

    <Button
        android:text="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/n2"/>
    <Button
        android:text="3"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/n3"/>
    <Button
        android:text="4"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/n4"/>
    <Button
        android:text="5"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/n5"/>
    <Button
        android:text="6"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/n6"/>
    <Button
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/n7"/>
    <Button
        android:text="8"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/n8"/>
    <Button
        android:text="9"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/n9"/>

    <Button
        android:text="CLR"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/clear"/>

    <Button
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/n0"/>

    <Button
        android:text="DEL"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/del"/>

</GridLayout>
```

Note: The `weight` in GridLayout is added from API level 21. Use support library for previous versions.